# Latex ifFileExist

Tags: r, knitr

```
\subsection{Checksum: Factor, Specific, and Total Variance}
Perhaps the most basic test of a regression model is if the factor and specific variances sum to equal the total variance.  Here, we 
present this diagnostic as an xy-plot, with the sum of factor and specific variance on the x-axis and the total variance on the y-axis.  We 
expect the plotted points to line up tightly along the identity line.

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[!h]

\centering

\includegraphics{\Sexpr{image_dir}xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf}

\caption{Total Variance vs. Sum of Factor and Specific Variance, All Instruments Passing Exposure Model.}

\end{figure}
```

**Question:**

How do i handle situation where "xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf" doesn't exist. File generated off of contents in a table, which in turn may or may not have data. final PDF generation process errors if it is missing "xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf"    How Can i handle this scenario ? I have tried /IfFileExist but it doesnt seem to working ..See following implementation.

```
\IfFileExists{{image_dir}{xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf}} { 

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[!h]

\centering

\includegraphics{\Sexpr{image_dir}{xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf}}

\typeout{File Exist: xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf}

\caption{Total Variance vs. Sum of Factor and Specific Variance, All Instruments Passing Exposure Model.}

\end{figure} } 

{\typeout{File DOESNT Exist: xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf}}
```

Comment: You don't have `\Sexpr{image_dir}` in your `\ifFileExists` expression, so I assume the evaluation of the folder+filename doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the tags, I assume you use `knitr`. Why not let R itself (silently) determine if the file exists?

```
<<chunkname,results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=
if (file.exists(file.path(image_dir, "xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf"))) {
   cat("\\clearpage\n")
   cat("\\begin{figure}[!h]\n")
   # and so on
}
else {
  cat("\\textbf{File does not exist.}\n\n")
}
@
```

Note the `results='asis'` chunk option. Each `cat`'d string will be outputted to the `.tex` file as it stands (hence the option's name). In other words, each `cat`'d string will be a LaTeX command to be compiled.

You can even generalize the above code by creating a fancy R function e.g. `include_if_exists(filename)`, and reuse it in many chunks.